# Spring web-flux with Wildfly Swarm

Tags: java, spring-webflux, wildfly-swarm

My current microservice is build on wildfly swarm. To create reactive API i plan to use Spring WebFlux.

How can I inject the spring Http handler into swarm undertow fraction ?

Is this possible, or do i need to re-write my application on spring boot?